# jquery add a class to $('<a/>').click(function(){...})

Tags: jquery, css

How can I add a class to tags such as `a` & `span` in these examples:

```
$('<a/>').click(function(){...})
$("<span/>").text(chars.substr(0, limit-1));
```

=================

Here is the full script. It adds spans and a tags to portions of text. I need to have classes added to the spans or a tags so that I can style the selections. It has to be jquery 1.3x:

```
var limit = 200,
chars = $("#showhideDiv").text();

if (chars.length > limit) {
    var visiblePart = $("<span/>").text(chars.substr(0, limit-1));
    var hiddenPart = $("<span/>").text(chars.substr(limit-1)).hide();
    var readMore = $('<a/>').click(function() {
             hiddenPart.toggle();
             readMore.toggle();
             readLess.toggle();
             return false;
         }).text ("Show more")
    var readLess = $('<a/>').click(function() {
             hiddenPart.toggle();
             readMore.toggle();
             readLess.toggle();
             return false;
        }).text("Show less").hide();
    $("#showhideDiv").empty()
        .append(visiblePart)
        .append(readMore)
        .append(hiddenPart)
        .append(readLess);
 }
```

Comment: what do you exactly want to achieve? add a class with jquery or a callback for an element with a class?

Comment: jquery 1.3? there is already jquery 1.6.2 why not use this?

Comment: I updated the original question with more detail.

Comment: i already saw, but why the very old jquery version 1.3? jquery 1.6 is much faster, safer and in many ways better and has much more features ... =)

Comment: Its not my call as to which ver of jquery is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [addClass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) method:

```
var visiblePart = $("<span>").text(chars.substr(0, limit - 1))
                             .addClass("yourClass");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('<a class="myClass" />').click(function() { /* ... */ });
```

or chain jQuery actions:

```
$('<a />').click(function() { /* ... */ }).addClass('myClass');
```

Comment: @naveen: What do you mean "what's the point"? The point is to add a class.

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
 $('<a/>', { class: 'myClass'} ).click(function()
```

when you create an element like this you can pass an object where you can define the attributes. look [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) for reference

Comment: +1 for great example and using different method off applying class.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = $('<a />');
a.addClass('class-name');

var span = $('<span />');
span.addClass('class-name');
```

You can also remove class if you need using `removeClass('class-name')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('<a />').click(function() { }).addClass('class');
$("<span/>").text(chars.substr(0, limit-1)).addClass('class');
```